# Stop jQuery Mobile slider at constraint value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider, uislider

I have a jQuery Mobile slider with a min value of 0 and a max value of 100 and a constraint value of 35.  If the slider starts at 0 and the user starts to slide the slider, how do I get the slider to stop at 35?

Comment: Then why is your max value set at 100?

Comment: The max value of the slider is 100, but depending on some other user determined factors, they might only be able to slide to 35. I can't make the max 35, because that would be confusing to the user if the max value changed from 100 to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script stops a slider at the value of 35:

```
$(document).on('change', '#slider-fill', function(e){
    if($("#slider-fill").val() > 35){
       $("#slider-fill").val(35);
       $("#slider-fill").next(".ui-slider").find("div").css("width","35%");
       $("#slider-fill").next(".ui-slider").find("a.ui-slider-handle").css("left","35%");
    }
});
```

Below you can find a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Slider Stop</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('change', '#slider-fill', function(e){
                if($("#slider-fill").val() > 35){
                   $("#slider-fill").val(35);
                   $("#slider-fill").next(".ui-slider").find("div").css("width","35%");
                   $("#slider-fill").next(".ui-slider").find("a.ui-slider-handle").css("left","35%");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Slider stop</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <label for="slider-fill">Input slider:</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sent me in the right direction.  I ended up using: $(#slider).slider('refresh').  Thanks!